# Why does my browser dont locate to this page with the pupeeteer skript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm new with NodeJS and i was wanted to make a bot. I pasted the code from the docs of puppeeteer in my IDE. and started the JS. But it doenst do anything in my browser. Here the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.youtube.com/');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

I did 'npm i puppeteer' but it still dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the code using Node.js.

If you called the file with the previos code for instance index.js in the same folder where you have this file you need to:

- create a node project => Execute in the terminal npm init -y
- install puppeteer module  => npm i puppeteer
- Execute the file ==> node index.js